# Consulta no MySQL quando existem duas ids

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL que grava informações de ligações de um PABX IP.
Ele armazena sempre a ligação com um `uniqueid` próprio.

Mas eu reparei que o tempo na URA também é armazenado na mesma tabela com o mesmo `uniqueid`.

Então quando alguém liga cai na URA e é atendido pela pessoa, são geradas duas entradas no banco de dados para a mesma ligação.

O meu problema é o seguinte: preciso que na *query*, quando dou um `select * from tabela;`, só exiba os dados da segunda entrada com exceção do campo `callduration` que tem que somar o valor das duas entradas.

Já andei procurando no google e não faço a menor ideia de como fazer uma *query* nesses padrões.

Segue um print de um exemplo na tabela:

[image: print]

Comment: Quais são os campos da tabela?

Comment: Não entendi se as duas entradas geradas referentes a mesma ligação tem ids iguais ou diferentes. Poderia esclarecer isso?

Comment: Posta os campos da tabela e as informações de forma mais coesa para podermos ajudar

Comment: `uniqueid` não é `PK` e nem `UK`??

Comment: nao , esse snep he um lixo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que:

- Todos os registros sejam duplicados.
- As duplicatas sempre formem um par tendo um "Dial" e um "Hangup" na coluna `lastapp` com o mesmo `uniqueid`.
- Todos os elementos do "Hangup" que estiverem preenchidos forem iguais ao do "Dial" (com exceção do `lastapp`).

Então, isso deve funcionar:

```
SELECT
    a.calldate AS calldate,
    a.clid, AS clid,
    a.src AS src,
    a.dst AS dst,
    a.dcontext AS dcontext,
    a.channel AS channel,
    a.dstchannel AS dstchannel,
    'Dial + Hangup' AS lastapp,
    a.lastdata AS lastdata,
    (a.duration + b.duration) AS duration,
    (a.billsec + b.billsec) AS billsec,
    a.disposition AS disposition,
    a.amaflags AS amaflags,
    a.accountcode AS accountcode,
    a.uniqueid AS uniqueid
FROM
    tabela a
INNER JOIN
    tabela b ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
WHERE a.lastapp = 'Dial'
AND b.lastapp = 'Hangup'
```

Se houverem registros que não são duplicados também e você quiser exibi-los também junto com o par duplicado (que deve ser considerado como um só registro), tente isso:

```
SELECT
    a.calldate AS calldate,
    a.clid, AS clid,
    a.src AS src,
    a.dst AS dst,
    a.dcontext AS dcontext,
    a.channel AS channel,
    a.dstchannel AS dstchannel,
    IF(ISNULL(b.uniqueid), a.lastapp, 'Dial + Hangup') AS lastapp,
    a.lastdata AS lastdata,
    (a.duration + COALESCE(b.duration, 0)) AS duration,
    (a.billsec + COALESCE(b.billsec, 0)) AS billsec,
    a.disposition AS disposition,
    a.amaflags AS amaflags,
    a.accountcode AS accountcode,
    a.uniqueid AS uniqueid
FROM
    tabela a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tabela b ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
WHERE a.lastapp = 'Dial'
AND (ISNULL(b.uniqueid) OR b.lastapp = 'Hangup')
```

Comment: vc ta fazenod um innerjoin na propria tabela por isso consegue pegar os 2 rsultados?

Comment: @JasarOrion Sim. Eu uso isso para juntar duas linhas diferentes da tabela.